# Sending e-mail with lotus notes- Parameter count mismatch

Tags: vb.net, email, lotus-notes

I am trying to run the code below and I see the error: "Could not execute code stage: Parameter count mismatch.". I know that it means that somewhere the parameter is missing but I am really unable to localize the line. Can anyone help me with that ?

```
 Dim SaveIt As Boolean
 Dim Maildb As Object 
 Dim UserName As String 
 Dim MailDoc As Object 
 Dim AttachME As Object 
 Dim Session As Object 
 Dim EmbedObj As Object 
 Dim DataBaseName As Object
 Dim ServerName As Object
 Dim DataBase As Object

Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
UserName = Session.UserName
DataBaseName = ""
ServerName = ""

  Maildb = Session.GetDataBase(ServerName, DataBaseName)
  If Maildb.ISOPEN = True Then
       'Already open for mail
  Else
      Maildb.OPENMAIL
  End If
 'Set up the new mail document

 MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT

 MailDoc.Form ("Memo")
 MailDoc.SendTo = Recipient
 MailDoc.Subject = Subject
 MailDoc.Body = Body
 MailDoc.Save(True, True)
 'MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True


 If Attachment <> "" Then
     AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Attachment")
     EmbedObj = AttachME.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", Attachment, "Attachment")
     MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("Attachment")
 End If

 'Send the document
 MailDoc.PostedDate=Now() 

 MailDoc.SEND(False, Recipient)

 'Clean Up
 Maildb = Nothing
 MailDoc = Nothing
 AttachME = Nothing
 Session = Nothing
 EmbedObj = Nothing
```

Comment: If it's a compile time error then i suspect your missed passing value for a parameter

Comment: You have two calls to MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("Attachment"). The second one is unnecessary and is not assigning the return value. I don't necessarily think that's causing the error, but you should clean that up and check it out. There's also no reason for you to be setting PostedDate. The mail system will do that for you. If, however, you want it PostedDate to be set in the saved copy, you should move your call to MailDDoc.save(True,true) so that it comes after your assignment of PostedDate.

Comment: Thank you for your input but still I have no clue where I missed the parameter value...

Comment: Thats why you NEVER write even one line of code without an error handler. This line is bullshit: `MailDoc.Form ("Memo")`. It should read `Maildoc.Form = "Memo"`. AND: the right item name for your attachments is „Body“ not „Attachments“

Comment: you are absolutely right, but I write it in kind of note and still do not know where is this parameter issue

Comment: Did you correct the errors Torsten pointed out?  The line MailDoc.Form("Memo") is treating Form as a function with one parameter, and that's incorrect. Form is not a function, but that could still be the source of the parameter count error.

Comment: Also, since you have a value in maildoc.sendTo, you don't need recipient in the maildoc.send() call.